# Can I use brew to install Node.js?

Tags: node.js, homebrew

I already have Brew on my MacOS, but I noticed some people suggest not using it for Node.js.

Can I still use brew, as it is easier? What are disadvantages of installing through brew if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used brew to install `npm` which automatically installs node.js. Didn't have any problem with it for at least one year.

Comment: Oh, so I install npm, and not node? Thanks. Sorry, cannot upvote you.

Comment: You can install npm and launch `node -v` from terminal to see version of installed nodejs